# index.html created by webpack includes vendor.js and app.bundle.js with a "/" where they are in the same dist folder

Tags: jquery, angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My webpack config is as following

```
config.output = isTest ? {} : {
path: __dirname + '/dist',
publicPath: baseUrl,
filename: isProd ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js',
chunkFilename: isProd ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js'
};

 if (!isTest) {

config.plugins.unshift(
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './app/index.ejs',
    inject: 'body',
    baseUrl: '/'
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css', {disable: !isProd})
);

config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js')
  );  
}
```

But when i run webpack it creates the index.html file in the dist folder with vendor.js and /app.bundle.js with a / although all three are in the same folder,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/app.bundle.js"></script></body>
```

hence when i run

```
webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --inline --progress --host 0.0.0.0
```

It does not render the page properly and throws error that it is not able to find jquery module as follows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ transition.js:59__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 26cc2c2…:50(anonymous function) @ no-op.js?59ab:1__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 26cc2c2…:50(anonymous function) @ no-op.js:2__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 26cc2c2…:50(anonymous function) @ loader.js:1__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 26cc2c2…:50(anonymous function) @ bootstrap 26cc2c2…:96__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 26cc2c2…:50(anonymous function) @ bootstrap 26cc2c2…:96(anonymous function) @ bootstrap 26cc2c2…:96 angular.js:68
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have managed to get around this, was just a baseURL in the webpack,

I got to know that when index.html is created by the webpack with vendor.js and app.bundle.js, it appends the baseURL to the scripts path inside the index.html

```
var baseUrl = '/abc/' 
inside index.html, it will be <script type="text/javascript" src="/abc/vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/abc/app.bundle.js"></script></body> </html>
```